# Gradle global plugin repository with Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I am new to Gradle, but need to build an opensource project that uses it, from my machine on the corporate network. The project has recently moved to Kotlin DSL, so some plugins are required.

I need to use our corporate Nexus server to fetch the plugin dependencies, and I would like to set this globally, because I don't want to have to modify the `settings.gradle.kts` in all the projects (I've tried this and it works)

If I want to do this globally, I understand from https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management that I need to have an `init.gradle.kts` file in my `USER_HOME/.gradle` directory. That's what I did, here's the content of the file :

```
    settingsEvaluated { settings ->
            settings.pluginManagement {
                repositories {
                    mavenLocal()
                    maven("https://my_corporate_nexus/")
                }
            }
    }
```

But when I then trigger my build, here's what I get :

```
* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 1: settingsEvaluated { settings ->
          ^ None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
              public open fun settingsEvaluated(p0: Closure<(raw) Any!>): Unit defined in Init_gradle
              public open fun settingsEvaluated(p0: Action<in Settings!>): Unit defined in Init_gradle
              public final fun settingsEvaluated(p0: Settings!.() -> Unit): Unit defined in Init_gradle
```

Below are my version details, as provided by `gradle -v` :

- Gradle 4.9
- Kotlin DSL:   0.18.4
- Kotlin:       1.2.41
- Groovy:       2.4.12

So it looks likes there's something obvious I am missing.

Any idea what it could be ?

Comment: see [Initialization Scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html).

Comment: I did already, I don't see the solution there

Answer (score 2):

it seems to work with :

```
settingsEvaluated {
        settings.pluginManagement {
            repositories {
                mavenLocal()
                maven("https://my_corporate_nexus/")
            }
        }
}
```

no `settings ->` .

I am not sure whether documentation is wrong or if my setup is specific though...